# Trouble with drawString method in Graphics class

Tags: java

Basically I am trying to use the drawString method, here is my code:

```
public void paintComponent( Graphics g )
    { 
        super.paintComponent( g );
        Graphics2D g2 = ( Graphics2D ) g;
        g2.setColor( Color.BLACK ); 
        g2.drawRect( 0, 0, 29, 29 ); 
        g2.drawString( mark, 11, 20 ); 
    }
```

I keep getting this error from Eclipse: "Open the Java build path property page of project". Does anyone know how to resolve this problem? 
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which of the solutions you found by googling this message didn't work?

Comment: Google tells me that your problem is not directly code related, but from Eclipse...

Comment: The error message is related to the configuration of your project, not the code.

Comment: configure your class path? missing jar? not selected JRE?

Comment: I have selected JRE.

Comment: Yes, I understand that this is not code related. But I don't know how to configure to resolve this issue.